# How can I remove elixir completly from Mac

Tags: elixir

I need to reinstall it . My earlier install is giving me problems . I need instructions specific to Mac  .Thanks for help .

Comment: This is off-topic. Try to ask you question over at [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to install Elixir using Homebrew:

```
brew install elixir
```

In case you need to get aquatinted with Homebrew, visit the https://brew.sh. There, you'll see the installation instruction, e.g.:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: The advice to set up Elixir with homebrew is not the best advice ever. `asdf` / `exenv` / `kiex` work great even on MacOS.

Comment: Homebrew is downloading latest version of Erlang and elixir . But I needed specific versions of both . But I have somehow manged to remove earlier versions and now I am using kiex and kerl for them for time being .

Comment: @arundhyani consider posting an answer for your own question, and, in a few days, accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you installed Elixir, so it is a bit difficult to know.  However, you can find where Elixir was installed by searching for the following files:

elixir
elixirc
iex
mix

If those are contained in a directory path like /usr/local/elixir/, you could just delete the elixir directory.  If they are in /usr/local/bin, I suppose you could just delete each Elixir related file from there.

In the future, I would recommend not installing Elixir via homebrew or a .dmg file.  Instead, use the asdf version manager:  https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf

It is easy to install and keep up to date.  Once you install it, you can list all possible Elixir versions by typing:

```
asdf list-all elixir
```

and you can install a new version of Elixir using:

```
asdf install elixir 1.7.3
```

Another benefit to using asdf is you can switch versions of Elixir dynamically, based on the directory you are in.  You simply have to include a file called .tool-versions in your project directory and then specify which version of Elixir you wish to use for that project, like this:

```
elixir 1.7.3
```

This allows you to have multiple projects, each with their own specific Elixir versions and dependencies.  This is extremely helpful and infinitely more helpful than installing Elixir via a binary or via homebrew.

asdf supports many different languages, such as Elixir, Erlang, Python, JavaScript, Java, etc.  It is a useful tool to know.